# Add multiple datatables (same schema) to current datasource

Tags: .net, vb.net

I want to add multiple datatables to a datasource witout creating each time (loop) a dataset by merging the current datasource to the new datatable.

This is my code :

```
' Those table are the same but have different data
' Tables() array, it's an example

For Each oTable As System.Data.DataTable In Tables
    DisplayResult(oTable, ColumnsAreCreated)
Next
```

Then I want to display the result in the grid :

```
Private Function DisplayResults(ByVal oTable As System.Data.DataTable, ByRef ColumnsAreCreated As Boolean) As Boolean

    If oTable.Rows.Count > 0 Then
        Dim compt As Integer = 0

        If Not ColumnsAreCreated Then
            Dim NewColumn As DevExpress.XtraGrid.Columns.GridColumn
            For Each oColumn As DataColumn In oTable.Columns
                NewColumn = grdv.Columns.AddField(oColumn.ColumnName)
                NewColumn.OptionsColumn.ReadOnly = True
                NewColumn.Visible = True
                NewColumn.VisibleIndex = compt
                compt += 1
            Next
            ColumnsAreCreated = True
            ' I want to do something like : grdctrl.DataSource += oTable
            grdctrl.DataSource = oTable

            grdv.OptionsView.ColumnAutoWidth = False
            grdv.BestFitColumns()
        End If
    End If

    Return True
End Function
```

I don't want to erase each time the current data, i want to do a concatenation of the current datasource in the gird with the following datatables, one by one.

I don't want to create a dataset, put in it the datatables and finally provide the gridcontrol the dataset.

There's a way to do it without creating a dataset ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly you want to "merge" all results, right?
Why not simply do that before binding to the grid in a single table?
If you want to merge after binding - bind the PGrid to a data source and member "Table" and then simply use Table.Merge(AddedTable). This should also automatically update your grid.
make sure you do not set keys to the table, otherwise you will get a regular merge (values will be updated if they are different and not added)
Hope I understood the question :)

Comment: In fact, I already tried to do it like this, but I was asking if there's a way to do it without storing a datatable in memory until all tables are read. In fact handling the gridcontrol datasource instead of creating a new table and storing in it the data.

Comment: Well the thing is, that Grid.DataSource store's only a reference to a "DataSet" or a "List" etc. (a link to a Collection storage thing). so in order to put multiple record sets into single place holder, it's logical that You'd use a "DataSet" or a DataTable, or a List. 

I would also suggest to do the joining in SQL, NOT in Memory, simple because it's more efficient. By doing so You can then user "serverMode" stuff (lazy loading etc)

Answer (score 0):

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!this.IsPostBack)
    {
        string constr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["constr"].ConnectionString;
        string query = "SELECT TOP 10 ContactName, City, Country FROM Customers;";
        query += "SELECT TOP 10 (FirstName + ' ' + LastName) EmployeeName, City, Country FROM Employees";

        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constr))
        {
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query))
            {
                using (SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter())
                {
                    cmd.Connection = con;
                    sda.SelectCommand = cmd;
                    using (DataSet ds = new DataSet())
                    {
                        sda.Fill(ds);
                        gvCustomers.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
                        gvCustomers.DataBind();
                        gvEmployees.DataSource = ds.Tables[1];
                        gvEmployees.DataBind();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This code is fully running code and hope it's help you.